# CSS 960 Fill page

Tags: css, height, fill

I'm using http://960.gs/ and I want my `container_12` class to fill the page.

EDIT: Fill only the height.

I tried:

```
.container_12{
    background-image:url(../images/background_2.png);
    background-position:center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: Elements set to `100%` widths and heights inherit from their parent elements width and height. If you don't have `height: 100%` on the `html, body` elements, it won't happen. Also, you have to manage padding and margin as well. I'm assuming 960.gs handles this for you, but just in case.

Comment: Thanks. I had body{height:auto;} and was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.container_12` class has a fixed width (you guessed it, 960px) so it's not going to fill the whole page. You want to set the background of its parent element - this can be `body` or a container div.

```
body {
    background-image:url(../images/background_2.png);
    background-position:center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Look at the style for [this demo page](http://960.gs/demo.html) - `.container_12` has the pink/white strip background and it only takes up 960px. The blue background taking up the entire page is set on `body`:

```
body {
  background: #123;
}
```

---

To make the `.container_12` take up the full height of the page, you need to set it's height, **along with the heights of its parent elements** to 100%;

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container_12 {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Why do you have to specify the height of the parent element? The height of `.container_12` is 100%, 100% *of what*? It's parent element.

Comment: You have reason. Sorry I have formuleted wrong the question. Only fill the height.

Answer (score 1):

Is this just because you want to have a large background image?  Why not just use:

```
body {
  background-image:url(../images/background_2.png);
  background-position:center top;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Tanks but in the background I have an other image.